# Can I delete php5's "error_log.txt"?

Tags: php, iis, iis-6

On our IIS6 server (running on a Microsoft Server 2003), the error_log.txt file located in the php5 folder has grown to a huge size of 500MB, and is massively fragmented.  It's so huge I can't even load it into a viewer to examine.

Can I just delete that file to reclaim space?  While IIS is running?

Comment: You really want to inspect the error log before deleting it.

Comment: THanks -- I compressed it (went from 500MB to 11MB!).  I'll bring it over to the Mac where I have better text tools available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can delete it. However PHP is going to continue to write its errors there, re-creating the file if it doesn't exist.

You can modify [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) in your php.ini to disable it, or direct it to Windows Event Log.

I would suggest using a *good* text editor like Notepad++ or TextPad to examine the contents of it before you delete it in case there is an error you need to know about. Those two generally don't try to load the entire file into memory at once like Notepad/Wordpad do.

Answer (score 1):

I belive the `error_log.txt` is automatically updated when there are errors, and if the file isn't found it's (re)created, so you *should* be able to remove it without a problem.